# Invoke command / Json Format Error during Amazon Web Services (AWS) Lambda Tutorial

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I've spent ~6 hours banging my head against an issue encountered in the official tutorial for Amazon Web Services (AWS) Lambda. I'm only using code provided in the tutorial..

I encounter the issue on **Step 2.3.2: Test the Lambda Function (Invoke Manually)**, found on this page:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example-upload-deployment-pkg.html?shortFooter=true

At this step we're creating an inputfile.txt using code provided by the AWS tutorial - the code simulates an "event" which triggers lambda.

Here's the code that goes into the inputfile.txt (I'm only copying & pasting from the tutorial):

```
{  
   "Records":[  
      {  
         "eventVersion":"2.0",
         "eventSource":"aws:s3",
         "awsRegion":"us-west-2",
         "eventTime":"1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
         "eventName":"ObjectCreated:Put",
         "userIdentity":{  
            "principalId":"AIDAJDPLRKLG7UEXAMPLE"
         },
         "requestParameters":{  
            "sourceIPAddress":"127.0.0.1"
         },
         "responseElements":{  
            "x-amz-request-id":"C3D13FE58DE4C810",
            "x-amz-id-2":"FMyUVURIY8/IgAtTv8xRjskZQpcIZ9KG4V5Wp6S7S/JRWeUWerMUE5JgHvANOjpD"
         },
         "s3":{  
            "s3SchemaVersion":"1.0",
            "configurationId":"testConfigRule",
            "bucket":{  
               "name":"sourcebucket",
               "ownerIdentity":{  
                  "principalId":"A3NL1KOZZKExample"
               },
               "arn":"arn:aws:s3:::sourcebucket"
            },
            "object":{  
               "key":"HappyFace.jpg",
               "size":1024,
               "eTag":"d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e",
               "versionId":"096fKKXTRTtl3on89fVO.nfljtsv6qko"
            }
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Here's the code which activates the inputfile.txt as an "event":

```
aws lambda invoke \
--invocation-type Event \
--function-name CreateThumbnail7 \
--region us-west-2 \
--payload file:/Users/username/inputfile.txt \
--profile adminuser \
outputfile.txt
```

and the error message about the invoke command:

> An error occurred (InvalidRequestContentException) when calling the Invoke operation: Could not parse request body into json: Unrecognized token 'file': was expecting 'null', 'true', 'false' or NaN
>   at [Source: [B@4aeacf9d; line: 1, column: 6]

(???)

Any ideas what could be happening / how to fix? Is this about the format of the inputfile.txt?

I've tried everything I can think of.. I must be doing something wrong or there must be an easy fix for the JSON formatting.

Comment: Are you sure your filepath is correct? Also the tutorial shows two forward slashes between 'file:' and 'filepath', i.e. file://filepath

Comment: Fairly certain about the filepath (changed my actual mac username to "username" for the code example above.

Although the tutorial shows two forward slashes, when using two a different error message shows up:

Error parsing parameter '--payload': Unable to load paramfile file://Users/jaredjamesluxton/inputfile.txt: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Users/username/inputfile.txt'

Comment: I suspect you're running into a relative vs. absolute path issue.  The JSON in your `inputfile.txt` is fine.  I suggest trying either `file:///Users/username/inputfile.txt` (3 slashes for absolute path) or `file://inputfile.txt` (2 slashes for relative path, assuming you're invoking the function from `/Users/username`).  And welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: Thanks @MikePatrick!

`file:///Users/username/inputfile.txt` did it - amazing! The output.txt returned an error (when the deployment package was config'd in Java) but I'll save that for another.. since I got the python deploy to work!

One last question.. how to mark questions as answered? Not seeing a place, and Google not instructive.

Comment: @Luxton - to mark a question as answered, there needs to be an answer posted that you accept.  In cases where the answer is discovered in the comments, you can do one of two things: 1)  Post the answer yourself, and accept it.  2)  Ask the commenter to "promote" their comment to an answer, so that you can accept it.

Comment: Luxton and @MikePatrick, please either post an answer for the question, or close/delete the question if it's not worth it for the community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those who find this thread and are struggling with Javascript deployment package step in the Amazon Web Services (AWS) Lamba tutorial, there are three separate issues in the tutorial guidelines which you must address:

1.) Make sure your Java environment is **8**, Java10 will throw a number of errors.

2.) @MikePatrick is correct, the path to your inputfile MUST be: `file:///Users/username/inputfile.txt`

3.) And finally, try using this pom.xml file (note the dependencies), this is the only combo that worked for me:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>doc-examples</groupId>
  <artifactId>lambda-java-example</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>lambda-java-example</name>

  <dependencies>


    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
      <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
  <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-events</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
  <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-log4j2</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
    <version>1.11.349</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
</dependency>



  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>



    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```